# Where are the performance counters in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm looking for any way to determine the performance of ASP.NET Core located on various different operating systems.

So far, all I have found is [this HTTP.sys-level set of counters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc307239(v=vs.85).aspx) but it's OS specific and not comprehensive [especially when compared to ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk122b4.aspx)

**Question**

How can I measure performance in ASP.NET Core?

Is this something I could implement myself with global counters?  (perhaps there is a Nuget with this out there)

Answer (score 8):

First of, performance counters are not a feature of ASP.NET, hence it's also not a concern of ASP.NET Core. They are part of windows.

Second, .NET Core (the **runtime**) do not implement it as linux or macOS don't have the concept of performance counters and .NET Core is meant to run on all of these platforms, as such you can't use them.

That being said, you can still use performance counters in ASP.NET Core, but only if you target .NET Framework instead of .NET Core.

The GitHub issues [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/3906) and [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1319)